# Facebook Graph - Create Event for Page returns Permission Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create a event assigned to a page, but its returning and OAuthException for a Permissions Error. Is there certain page types that you can not create events for as this works for other user pages?

If I use the users access token, and list the permissions (/me/permissions) it does show that I have the create_event permission. I then list out the accounts that user has (/me/accounts) and grab the access token and use that to create an event that is what gives me the Permission Error posting as (/me/events) which as I said works for other pages for a different user. I can't seem to figure out why this user can not create events.

Comment: Does it work as /{page id}/events instead of /me/events?

Comment: So I finally figured it out. While testing this, it created an event and logged in my application the EventID. So my app was actually trying to update an event that was not listed/did not have permissions for. Removing this entry allowed my program to create the event.

Comment: Wish I had the ability to post it as an answer :(

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize I was posting an event I'd with the other variables. So it was trying to update an event that was already deleted from Facebook.